# How to update tags array list in Elasticsearch and Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I Want to update the user's favorite products and I cant do that with python there is any solution for that. this example is the same as the user add and remove tags

this is the schema I have on customers INDEX

```
"hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "customers",
                "_type": "customer",
                "_id": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "uid": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                    "email": "george@gmail.com",
                    "favorites": [],  < ---- this is the problem
                    "history": [],
                    "settings": {},
                    "purchases ": [],
                    "created": 1507892081201,
                    "updated": 1507892081201
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

As you see I want the array **favorites** to store the ids of the products the user selected as favorite products. And I want to update this doc to be like this:

```
"hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "customers",
                "_type": "customer",
                "_id": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "uid": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                    "email": "george@gmail.com",

                    "favorites": ['product_id_1', 'product_id_2', 'product_id_3'],  < ---- this is the problem

                    "history": ['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3'],
                    "settings": {},
                    "purchases ": [],
                    "created": 1507892081201,
                    "updated": 1507892081201
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have tried this code but is does not work:

```
fav_product = {
   "user_id": "user_1",
   "product_id": "favorite_product_1",
}

def add_favevorite_product(fav_product):
    ''' Add new favorite product '''

    user_id = fav_product['user_id']
    product_id = fav_product['product_id']

    print('Start new favorite product')

    timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    doc = {
        'favorites' : "ctx._source.tags.add(product_id)",
        'created': timestamp,
        'updated': timestamp
    }


    es.update(index="customers", doc_type='customer', id=user_id, body={"doc": doc})
    es.indices.refresh(index="customers")
    return jsonify({'message': 'customer_updated'}), 200
    # return jsonify(fav_product), 200
#end
```

Have this response from the server:

```
"hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "customers",
                "_type": "customer",
                "_id": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "uid": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                    "email": "george@gmail.com",
                    "favorites": "ctx._source.favorites.add(AV8PsBG_oWUfB334-p5b)",
                    "history": [],
                    "settings": {},
                    "purchases ": [],
                    "created": 1507893703655,
                    "updated": 1507893703655
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def add_favevorite_product(fav_product):
''' Add new favorite product '''

user_id = fav_product['user_id']
product_id = fav_product['product_id']

print('Start new favorite product')


doc = {
    "script" : {
        "inline":"ctx._source.favorites.add(params.product_id)",
        "params":{
            "product_id":product_id
        }
    }
}
es.update(index="customers", doc_type='customers', id= user_id, body=doc)
es.indices.refresh(index="test")
```

Comment: OMG BROOOOOOOOOOOO THANX, I was searching for that all the day. I am sow happy you help me